# How to set different values to a property based on the device orientation

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development

I would like to change the `top` property value of the `Positioned` widget according to screen orientation.

I didn't know how to do it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user `MediaQuery.of(context).orientation`
It can respond to the orientation of the device.

```
Positioned(
  top: MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait ? portraitValue : landScapeValue,
child: //your code
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As from the [official flutter article](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/orientation#2-use-an-orientationbuilder-to-change-the-number-of-columns), you can use the `OrientationBuilder` to manage your widgets based on the device orientation like this:

```
  OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    return Positioned(
      top: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 10 : 50,
      child: /*...0*/
    );
  },
),
```

change `10` and `50` with your values.

And if you're willing to get the orientation of the device in other places other than widgets in your app, like methods, for example, you can use the `MediaQuery.of(context).orientation` to get the actual orientation of the device.

```
printOrientation() {
  print(MediaQuery.of(context).orientation);
 }
```

Check this for more info:

[OrientationBuilder()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OrientationBuilder-class.html)

[MediaQuery.of(context).orientation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/orientation.html)